# isinstance Assertion during pytest give full level of Class instead of locally imported Class?

Tags: python, instance, pytest

I currently have a project with the similar looking tree using Pycharm 2019.3, python 3.7.4 and pytest 5.3.5

```
rootproject
|
|--elements
|  |
|  --liquid
|  |  |
|  |  - water.py
|  |
|  --solid
|     |
|     - earth.py
|
-- test_foobar
   |
   --bar_test
   | |
   | -- test_bar.py
   | |
   | -- test_bar_bar.py
   |
   --foo_test
     |
     -- test_foo.py
     |
     -- test_foo_foo.py
```

with earth.py and water.py having the corresponding classes of Earth and Water

And a setup of .pth in my site-packages folder to the liquid and solid folder. (I know it's probably not best practice, but bear with me here)

The test module for instance assertion are done as the following:

```
import pytest

# one module has this import
from water import Water


def test_type():
  element = Water() # or Earth()
  assert isinstance(element, Water)  # or Earth

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main()
```

I currently use the pytest framework to run my testing, with bar_test and foo_test as testing packages for different packages in the source folder (currently not pictured in project tree).

Here's the problem.

When I run pytest only for test_bar.py or the test_package, bar_test, the isinstance assertion was capable of checking the element instance as Water/Earth class correctly.

However, when I run the test at test_foobarspy, I get a failure from pytest that the the element is not of **Water** class, but instead of **elements.liquid.water.Water** class.

I'm going to be debugging this in the next few days, but I'm rather confused that this even happen in the first place, because the project was running okay three weeks ago if I had run the pytest through my IDE from test_foobar, and no one changed the importing convention.

Could anyone help me with why this happen in the first place for pytest and what to do to fix it other than removing the .pth and inserting the full level in the test module?

Comment: You are importing both from `elements.liquid.water` and from `water`, which happens when both the `rootproject` *and* the `elements/liquid` directories are on your `sys.path` and you are not using package imports correctly.  **Don't use `from water import ...` when `water` is not a top-level package**.

Comment: And there is your problem: *And a setup of .pth in my site-packages folder to the liquid and solid folder. (I know it's probably not best practice, but bear with me here)*. Don't do that.